# TypeScript Set<> collection getting value via index

Tags: typescript, collections, set

Hello everyone I'm new in TypeScript and maybe i don't see something obvious but here is my question:

```
const someSet = new Set();
someSet.add(1)
console.log(someSet[0])
```

gives me undefined can someone explain me why we cant get value via index? And how can i do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use an iterator:

```
var iterator = someSet.values();
console.log(iterator.next().value);
```

You can learn more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set).

TypeScript doesn't throw when you do `someSet[0]` because you can also access the properties using the index syntax:

```
someSet["values"]
```

Answer (score 4):

[Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) is part of ES6, not TypeScript. It's property is to be an iterable collection of unique values though not with a fixed index. Do not rely on indices to access these items since they're not ordered (use an `Array` instead). If you would like to iterate over a set you can always use `someSet.forEach()`.

Answer (score 2):

Probably because [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) does not have indexer.

You can get value by doing so:

```
let val = [...mySet][0];
```

Comment: If you want to use this approach wouldn't it be better to use the first element from the iterator instead of accessing all values?
 `someSet.values().next().value`

Comment: 0 index was used as an example. You can use this approach to access any element.

Comment: Agreed. Still a `Set` is not supposed to be used for indexed collections =/ You can't guarantee that the first element you add will be the first element you receive by definition